# Checking if class from parameters is equal (instanceOf) needed class. Trying to make generic class

Tags: java, android

The logic is that as a parameters i am getting 1-Something.class, 2-Listlist, 3 String param. So the main goals of this method are: 1) Understand which class case we are looking for (if/else statement) 2) With help of the loop in the list of the objects will find needed ONE object with help of String param and return this filtered object out. Here is my code. But i have issues: 1) What is the correct way of comparing given class from parameter with Something.class 2) How to make generic loop for received list?

My code sample

```
private <T> Object searchNeededObject(Class<T> theClass, List<?> list, String param) {
    Object result = null;
    //Checking if needed class is Image.class
    if (theClass instanceof Image) {
        //Chacking in our list for needed object with help of param
        for (Image neededImage : list) {
            if (neededImage.getLinks().equals(param) || neededImage.getName().equals(param)) {
                //Have found needed object
                result = neededImage;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Which `Java` version do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delimit the list to T type

```
List<T> list
```

for compare the class, use equals method  because  theClass is not a instance

```
theClass.equals(Image.class);
```

as the for is of T items you need a cast for eachItem

```
private <T> Object searchNeededObject(Class<T> theClass, List<T> list, String param) {
    Object result = null;

    // Checking if needed class is Image.class
    if (theClass.equals(Image.class)) {
        // Chacking in our list for needed object with help of param
        for (T item : list) {
        if (item instanceof Image) {
            Image neededImage = (Image) item;
            if (neededImage.getLinks().equals(param) || neededImage.getName().equals(param)) {
            // Have found needed object
            result = neededImage;
            }
        }
        }
    }
    return result;
    }
```

in this example the 'instanceof' is redundant because the list type is limited to the 'the Class' argument  as type

Comment: Thanks thats something i was looking for. I edited it little bit. But it works.